# What to do when a question isn't a question

Tags: discussion

So I came across [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138383/19-04-installation-shortcomings#). I flagged the "question" as too opinioned based but what should one actually do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a posted question is not a question, or it is completely unclear what is being asked, it is best to use the "Unclear what you are asking" flag / close reason.  And you should probably leave a comment on the post as well indicating that it's not clear what's being asked (if you haven't already done so).

This is the best suited flag/close reason for cases where a clear question is not being asked.  ("Primarily Opinion Based" usually implies that individuals won't get any fact-driven answers, not that the question is unclear or nonexistent.)